# Use Python to resize the active window to half the screen size in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, window-management

This question is a follow up to: [Manipulate window size in linux via compiled code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424214/manipulate-window-size-in-linux-via-compiled-code)

Per the title, I want to resize the active window to half the screen size (either on the left or the right of the screen. I can do this with a bash script as follows (per the answer to the previous question):

```
#!/bin/bash

w_h=$(xrandr | awk '/\*/{sub(/[0-9\.\*\+]*$/, ""); sub("x", " "); $1=$1/2; print}')
w=${w_h% *} ; h=${w_h#* }

wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_horz,maximized,vert
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,${w},0,${w},${h}
```

However, this method has a noticeable but not severe lag of 0.25 seconds on my laptop that I would like to get down to 0.1 seconds. How can I achieve the same affect as the above bash script in python?

Comment: Just an update, the line:

    `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_horz,maximized,vert`

should be:

    `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_horz,maximized_vert`

i.e.

**maximized,vert** should be **maximized_vert**

Answer (score 0):

The lag you getting is caused by xrandr command it's going to be slow anyway. You can reduce this time by parsing output of `xdpyinfo  | grep 'dimensions:'`. From python you could call this command using subprocess.Popen.