# How to figure out which application window is on the top?

Tags: macos, user-interface, unix, kernel

I am a noob when it comes to Desktop GUIs. Is there a way for me to programmitically figure out which application window is the top most in terms of display environment?

So, basically, I can have a process running in the background, that might then change the behavior of the top-most (or say the selected) window. My go to operating system would be MacOS (then Linux family). Also, for instance, there is an app called [spectacle app](https://www.spectacleapp.com), which listens to key bindings to snap resize and move active windows on MacOS.

Comment: A similar unanswere question can be found here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444377/use-python-to-resize-the-active-window-to-half-the-screen-size-in-linux)

Comment: Here's a better hint (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python)